# Can't retrieve TFS workspaces in c# with tfs API

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, tfs-sdk

I need to Get Latest Version of a TFS workspace that isn't mapped on my computer.

This is my code:

```
using (TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
    new Uri("http://tfs:8080/tfs/project"), 
    new NetworkCredential("tfs", "pwd")))
{
    tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();

    VersionControlServer vcs = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

    Workspace w = vcs.GetWorkspace("VM-TFS", vcs.AuthorizedUser);

    // Implement w.Get(.....)
}
```

The problem is that on `GetWorkspace()` i received an exception: `"TF14061: the workspace VM-TFS;DELTA\\tfs does not exist."` (where the `'DELTA'` before the username is our domain.)

I'm sure that the username is correct, that he is the owner of the workspace and the workspace name is correct too.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I found the problem. Initially I have imported the .dll directly with the intelliSense. In this way I think that Visual Studio reference the dlls that came with him.
I tried to remove all them and to install with NuGet the 'Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient', and now it works!

Comment: Did you try getting a list of **all** workspaces and seeing what comes back?

Comment: By code with the API you mean? Because I didn't found a way to do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

Initially I have imported the .dll directly with the intelliSense. In this way I think that Visual Studio reference the dlls that came with him. I tried to remove all them and to install with NuGet the `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient`, and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with the code below and got a successful result, you may have a try:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;

namespace GetLatest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/TeamProjectCollection"));
            var versioncontrols = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
            var workspace = versioncontrols.GetWorkspace("test", versioncontrols.AuthorizedUser);
            workspace.Get();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the same thing that I did... Do you think that the problem could be related with the workspace's permission? (I gave the `NetworkCredenials` to the `TfsTeamProjectCollection` constructor for that...)

Comment: If you use my code, are you able to get the workspace?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. However I tried, I replaced the Uri and the workspace name with my own and it didn't work...Same exception...

Comment: Could you try to create a new workspace to see whether it can be recognized?